# Connect to sharepoint on premise site from my Asp,net

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to connect to SharePoint on-premise website using .NET Core, this website requires authentication I didn't find a way to connect to it most of the results on the net are related to SharePoint online.

Comment: Try to use Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM 16.1.20211.12000 or the latest version. Accoring to [this link](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/16585795-support-net-core-with-csom) and [this blog](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blogs/net-standard-version-of-sharepoint-online-csom-apis/), from the version 16.1.20211.12000 onwards, the CSOM package support .net core.

Comment: @ZhiLv it supports SharePoint online not on-premise

Answer (score 0):

Each SP OnPrem version has a dedicated CSOM nuget which you may use to connect.

- [2013 csom nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint2013.CSOM/)
- [2016 csom nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint2016.CSOM/)
- [2019 csom nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint2019.CSOM/)

the connection and getting some data will look similar to this (I didn't check this code but more or less it should fallow this approach )

```
     using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("URL"))
    {
       var web = context.Web;
       var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("some list title");
       context.Load(list, includes => includes.Title);
       context.ExecuteQuery();
    // after this line the list will be initialized 
    }
```

hope this will be of any help

Comment: I guess all these packages are .Net Framework, not .net Core?

Comment: TBH I am not sure but I would suspect that it is .NET Framework. The core is more used in SP Online and there is a really cool nuget for it as well here -> https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/using-the-sdk/readme.html

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for .net core on-prem model. Guess I should implement it by myself?